# Сохранение referer в cookies

Tags: http, php, cookie

Здравствуйте.

Стоит задача: сохранить реферер в куки. Использую это код:

```
<? 
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && (!$_COOKIE['last_ref'])) { 
    SetCookie( 'last_ref', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
}

?>
```

Если за время жизни сессии приходить на целевую страницу из разных источников, то в куки сохраняется самый первый источник и не перезаписывается каждый раз (что и нужно).

Проблема в том, что кука перезаписывается каждый раз, когда бродишь по собственным страницам сайта (на каждой странице приведен верхний код), несмотря на условие существования куки с именем "`last_ref`". Если же запретить запоминать реферер, совпадающий с собственным сайтом, то кука вообще пустая.

Что не так в коде?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос что понимать под разными источниками. Если это переходы с других сайтов - то соответственно нужна проверка на это.

```
$MySite = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];

if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) and substr($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],0,strlen($MySite)) != $MySite) {
  # Проверяем куки и если нужно устанавливаем
}
```

Просто browser каждый раз выставляет Referer: когда переходит по ссылкам (неважно какого сайта своего или чужого)

Answer (score 1):

Не вдумываясь сильно, можно предложить создать в $_SESSION флаг, сигнализирующий о том, что реферер был установлен. Таким образом, за время существования сессии реферер не будет изменяться... Что-то вроде

```
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && (!$_COOKIE['last_ref']) && ! isset($_SESSION['referer_saved'])) 
{
 SetCookie( 'last_ref', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 $_SESSION['referer_saved'] = true;
}
```

пожалуй, можно убрать проверку существования $_COOKIE['last_ref']